Projection Matrix to Intrinsic parameters
I want to convert a Projection Matrix in the following form:

Where:

f = fov
a = aspect ratio = width / height
F = far plane
N = near plane

to the Intrinsic parameters matrix:


s = skew
(fx, fy) = Focal Length
(x0, y0) = Principal Point Offset

I've already tried to perform the conversion by myself and this is the result I got:
s = 0
fx = (w/2) * (1/(a*tan(f/2)))
fy = (h/2) * (1/tan(f/2))
x0 = (w/2)
y0 = (h/2)


The issue is: I'm doing the conversion because I want to feed the intrinsic parameters to a model that was trained on the DTU dataset, using real camera calibration values. Deriving the intrinsic parameters as I've written above doesn't look to work (i.e. outputs garbage). Comparing my intrinsic parameters to the dataset intrinsic parameters, I see that:
My values are e.g.:
256.00000 0.00000   384.00000 
0.00000   288.00000 288.00000 
0.00000   0.00000   1.00000 

Their values are e.g.:
347.07959 0.00000   98.78471 
0.00000   345.98160 74.28828 
0.00000   0.00000   1.00000 

My fx, fy values are roughly similar; but my x0, y0 values look wrong (also note fy = y0).
Are my calculations wrong?
Also, as far as I've understood extrinsic parameters are the CG view matrix (from world-space to view-space), right?
